# restore derby database online

Tags: java, derby

From a java application (junit test) I am trying to restore a derby file database. The derby server has been started as a standalone server (so not embedded). I am using the following code.

```
String url = "jdbc:derby://localhost/V4_0_0/ambikas";
String urlToRestoreFrom = "C:/javadev/workspace/trunk/ambi-kas-lib/derby/V4_0_0_backup/ambikas";

DriverManager.getConnection(url + ";createFrom=" + urlToRestoreFrom);
log.debug("db restored ...");
```

When I run the code no exceptions are thrown from Derby's side. Everything seems to go fine but no restore has taken place. The directory "url" where I want to restore the db contains the current database. According to the derby documentation this should work however. The restore functionality should replace the current db.

I know there have been some threads before on this topic but none of them seem to solve my problem. I am stuck with it for weeks now.

Comment: Have you seen the comments here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11073969/java-derby-restorefrom-does-nothing ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not "createFrom=", it's "restoreFrom=".

See these docs for more information: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.9/adminguide/cadminhubbkup98797.html

Comment: I indeed made a mistake by setting createFrom instead of restoreFrom. It was a typo. My mistake. I have read the derby docs in the past and that was exactly what I have implemented...